# Errors reading or parsing /etc/raddb/radiusd.conf

Tags: freeradius, radius

**Dears**,

I am new to freeRADIUS, I have installed freeRADIUS v3 in centos7. I am not able to start the radiusd service. I got the error  Job for radiusd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status radiusd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

when i run  /usr/sbin/radiusd -X i got

including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unix
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/unpack
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/utf8
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/eduroam_cui_log
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/cui
including configuration file /etc/raddb/mods-config/sql/cui/sqlite/queries.conf
Unable to open file "/etc/raddb/mods-config/sql/cui/sqlite/queries.conf": No such file or directory
Errors reading or parsing /etc/raddb/radiusd.conf

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `Unable to open file "/etc/raddb/mods-config/sql/cui/sqlite/queries.conf": No such file or directory` - some of your configuration is missing. This means that either you didn't install FreeRADIUS correctly, or you have edited and broken the configuration afterwards.

If you installed from packages, ensure you installed the `freeradius-config` package.

If you installed from source, move your existing configuration out of the way (e.g. `mv /etc/raddb /etc/raddb.bak`) and then do `make install` again - this will reinstall the (full) default configuration.

Comment: the issue comes when I create a symlink for cui in mods-enabled and mods-available. but I need to link them

Comment: The missing config file definitely exists in the default config: https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.2.x/raddb/mods-config/sql/cui/sqlite/queries.conf which means somehow the file is missing from your local install.

Comment: thanks for your replay. I am installing mysql, not SQLite and the file is available inside /etc/raddb/mods-config/sql/cui/mysql/queries.conf.. in which file should I change the path ??

Comment: I have followed the instructions here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1155098 , but still not solved

Comment: It's the CUI config, not the main SQL config. So try editing `mods-enabled/cui` and setting the dialect there - or if you don't need CUI then remove the `mods-enabled/cui` symlink entirely.